# can I update a cart item's price using REST API in woocommerse? Not in the user's session, but using a cart's or cart item's id?

Tags: cart, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to update a product's price at the time the customer adds the item to cart. For some reason my webhook calls me 5 times when I add one item...

My plan was to call my own server with the webhook and pass the cart and item ids. Then my server would make REST calls to multiple places and calculate a cost that is more than the product costs to me. Then it would update the item prices in the cart using the ids (and not users session like CoCart). Checkout would send order_created and then I would "bake" the digital products and deliver them with email, when I'm sure the customer paid for them.

It seems the official REST API supports adding new products. How nice. The problem in creating products with correct prices in them is not the way to go here. I need to get the customer input for the product first, to figure out how much it costs. Some of the customer input is random, so I can get the price after I see the input.

It is not impossible, since it is just an update to a cart item and I know the ids already. Maybe I need to create my own API endpoint, but I don't have the slightest clue how to start?

PUT /../../v3/cart/ and give item id with price ="399€" with json

I have gone through all documents I can find and even some plugins, but it seems they were all for headless implementations of woocommerse.